# Java change Bytecode - not working

Tags: java, bytecode, decompiler

First of all i want to make sure, that i am not doing illegal operations to modify software against the rules (except changing the bytecode is already against the rules - it is a freeware, and i want to change one line to improve my productivity)

- i used JDGui to decompile the code to understand the code
- DirtyJoe to edit the bytecode (no decompiling and compiling)
- Winrar to extract the .class file from the JAR to desktop, modify it with DirtyJoe and place the modified class file again with Winrar into the jar

The problem is that, when i change bytecode of a class file inside a jar, the program detects this and won't execute this code at all.

What i alreay tried: 
Changing the bytecode of a class file: Just inserting a whitespace and deleting the white space again (i used the windows editor in this case)
- result: All Methods of this file wont execute at all. The software calls some logger or event dispatcher.

So i think the software detects this modifications (even if i did just entered a whitespace and deleted this again). Ive already tried to change the "modification date" in the file meta data, but this won't work.

You guys have suggestions what i could try?

**EDIT #1: ANSWER TO COMMENTS:** How to know whether the software checks hash signs or uses encryption?

**EDIT #2: IMPORTANT IMAGE !! :** 
[Link to the picture!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQcMQ.png)

Comment: Afaik changing bytecode is *not* per se against the rules.

Comment: Some software uses *asymetrical encryption* te verify the "signature" of the software. In that case there is not much you can do. I know most ATMs in Europe have a CPU that verifies software that way such that the ATM knows it is running software produced by the vendor and not by a hacker.

Comment: If you insert "whitespace" into a class file, all the internal indexes will be wrong. Also if the jar is signed, then the signed hash for that file will be wrong.

Comment: “inserting a whitespace” implies that you are modifying the byte code in a text editor. This is likely to break a binary file; sometimes a text editor will break it even if you just save without modifying it. From that, the conclusion that the software has some sort of “detection” is very far-fetched. You should post the actual error message.

Comment: You can try to decompile the class file that you want to modify, and modify decompiled source and bundle the JAR again. This would be a lot easier if the debug information was preserved during the original compilation, but I doubt that would be the case if it's a commercial application.

Comment: Ok thanks! But are there ways to check whether the software checks hashs or uses encryption etc..?

Comment: “All Methods of this file wont execute at all” is a very thin problem description. You’re still talking about a single class, don’t you? So the software still works, but silently skips the execution of the methods of a single particular class? That doesn’t even remotely sound like a protection measure.

Comment: You are really funny. The call tree shown in the picture clearly indicates that you have an exception and that it has been printed to the console. *Why don’t you post that exception?*

Comment: Said to see you are confined by the persons of justice that you have to put a disclaimer and present images in a twirling way.

Answer (score 2):

First off - if you are trying to modify an obfuscated Java app, NEVER rely on recompilation. Compilation and decompilation are both lossy processes, and if you are able to recompile the results of decompilation, it is only by luck. That doesn't mean decompilation is useless - it is still useful for *understanding* the code. However, you shouldn't rely on it for *modifying* obfuscated code.

In order to modify code, you're best off using the [Krakatau assembler and disassembler](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau). This allows you to modify bytecode directly, no matter how obfuscated the app is (assuming that it still has valid classfiles).

So first you should try using the disassembler to edit the code, which will tell you if your problem is soley due to recompilation issues. However, it is more likely that the app is doing some sort of integrity check, in which case you'll have to figure out where the check is and either remove or bypass it. Unfortunately, there's not much that can be said about that without more specific information about the code in question.

Comment: Thanks for replying ! :) Just to make clear:
- i used JDGui to decompile the code to understand the code
- DirtyJoe to edit the bytecode (not decompiling and compiling)
- Winrar to extract the .class file from the JAR to desktop, modify it with DirtyJoe and place the modified class file again with Winrar into the jar

Comment: I have added the picture of the called methods, please look at it :)